# Cannot install pgLoader - No matching package to install: 'sbcl'

Tags: linux, redhat, pgloader

I am trying to install pgLoader on RHEL9 machine, but can't get pass sbcl requirement:

I followed instruction here:
https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/blob/master/INSTALL.md

However sbcl is not in EPEL EL9, so I tried to install it manually. I believe it worked fine:

```
SBCL has been installed:
 binary /usr/local/bin/sbcl
 core and contribs in /usr/local/lib/sbcl/

Documentation:
 man /usr/local/share/man/man1/sbcl.1
[root@pc-853 sbcl-2.2.9-x86-64-linux]#

[janek@pc-853 bin]$ sbcl
This is SBCL 2.2.9, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
```

However when I try to run  `sudo yum-builddep pgloader.spec` now it fails

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:15 ago on Fri 07 Oct 2022 10:18:09 PM CEST.
Package openssl-devel-1:3.0.1-41.el9_0.x86_64 is already installed.
No matching package to install: 'sbcl'
Package zlib-devel-1.2.11-31.el9_0.1.x86_64 is already installed.
Not all dependencies satisfied
Error: Some packages could not be found.
```

I am total noob when it comes to Linux but I imagine this is because sbcl was not installed with yum. Is there a way to make it work on this os version? Should I just install older version of OS? Here's host info:

```
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.0 (Plow)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:9::baseos
            Kernel: Linux 5.14.0-70.26.1.el9_0.x86_64
```

Comment: I guess that call is entirely up to you; stepping down two major releases for one tool seems like a bad idea in terms of maintenance and security, though.  You might get lucky with a tool like `alien` to convert from a `.deb` to an `.rpm`. Failing that you could also try `installpkg` to build an RPM out of the source package for you ... I haven't tried either, hence just a comment rather than an answer. Or you could learn how to build proper RPMs ;)

Comment: @tink You mean to convert pgloader `.deb` to `.rpm`? won't it still complain about missing sbcl?

Comment: No, I meant the sbcl.deb => RPM